# Convert VB.net Code into C#.net

Tags: vb.net, c#-4.0

I am working on a C#.net. I have a code of vb.net and I want to convert those code into C#.
I have done all my task but while running application it gives me a error of object not set to an object reference. below is my VB.net code. I have used third party ddl in my code so ExchangeList is a class of that dll.

```
 Private WithEvents moExchanges As ExchangeList
Private Sub RequestChartData()

        Trace.WriteLine("Init")           
        moExchanges = moHost.MarketData.Exchanges
 End Sub
```

Now below is my C#.code

```
  Private Host moHost;
  Private ExchangeList moExchanges;
 private void RequestChartData()
    {

        Trace.WriteLine("Init");           
        moExchanges = moHost.MarketData.Exchanges;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is `moHost`?  Where is it initialized?  You're getting the error because it's been declared but not initialized - it's null.

Comment: Not really sure but I think `WithEvents`, means that `moExchange` is suppose to raise an event. The error you are getting for NRE, is because you haven't initialized moExchange, you need to do that with the `new` keyword,

Comment: I'm pretty sure (based on the code shown) that **`moHost`** is the offender, not `moExchanges`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to tell you with 100% certainty the source of your `object not set to an object reference.` without seeing more code, but the error appears to be telling you that `moHost` is null - in other words, you haven't created an instance of the object yet.

So when you try to call `MarketData.Exchanges` on the object (so you can assign it to `moExchanges`, it's throwing the error.

Find `moHost` in your code and make sure you have that you have assigned an instance of that object to it (by calling it's constructor, like `moHost = new Host()` or whatever the constructor is), and this should fix your error.

**UPDATE**

You never initialize `moHost`.  This line:

```
private Host moHost;
```

Simply declares the object - at this point it's null.  So when you try to access any instance methods/properties, you get the object not set to an object reference error.

You need to create an instance of `moHost` by calling it's constructor, something like this:

```
private Host moHost = new Host();
```

The constructor may require parameters - take a look at the documentation for the third-party DLL (intellisense in the IDE may also tell you what parameters, if any, are needed).

This will take care of your error.

Answer (score 0):

()Instead of:

```
Private Host moHost;
Private ExchangeList moExchanges;
```

I think you need to write it as:

```
Private Host moHost = New Host();
Private ExchangeList moExchanges = New ExhangeList();
```